# Як невдобно получилось — What does it even mean?

Tags: значення-слів, росіянізм

Sometimes I see Як in a sentence. What does it mean? And what does this sentence mean?

Comment: It's Ukrainian language, not Russian.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because Questions that **do not demonstrate an attempt to self-answer** [are off-topic](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/223/8). You can improve it by adding what you have done so far, even if it is incomplete. Also, both *«невдобно»* and *«получилось»* are clearly [barbarisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarism_(linguistics)); it has nothing to do with Ukrainian language. Voting to **move it back** to [russian.se].

Comment: @bytebuster, it's [surzhyk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surzhyk) — mixture of Russian and Ukrainian languages. There are different kinds of surzhyk, but it often tends to use Russian lexicon and Ukrainian pronunciation. In this case I personally am an "inclusionist" — I tend to consider surzhyk as a part of Ukrainian, though many may argue with me.

Comment: @Sasha, тоїсть, ми тіпєрь всє вапроси, касающієся московського язика, авторітєтним рішенієм щітатимемо вапросами про український суржик, я вас правільна пойняв? :-(

Comment: @bytebuster, Ви незгодні з тим, що «як невдобно получилось» — це суржик?

Comment: Person who asked this couldn't care less about this thread whatsoever. Apart from that, I kind of agree with both of you, the main problem is that the question lies in between two languages, it's not really about Russian but it's not really about Ukrainian and indeed there is no attempt to make a self-answer which clashes with more general SE rules, and which should have clearly signified that YES, THIS QUESTION ABOUT UKRAINIAN. Also this question wasn't asked here originally so I would be inclined to close this as an off-topic.

Comment: surzhyk is not Ukrainian but it is a way a lot of Ukrainians speak and other surzhyk questions already were answered without any additional questions so this creates the contradiction.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it fails to show any research effort.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it fails to show any research effort.

Answer (score 5):

It's written in [surzhyk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surzhyk) and means something like "It is such an awkward situation." Please, don't use it in a real conversation. The correct spelling is "Як незручно вийшло." It can be used when you feel sorry about the situation or in a sarcastic way when you are not actually sorry.

Answer (score 5):

*[Як](http://sum.in.ua/s/jak)* means "how".

*Невдобно* ([surzhyk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surzhyk)) or *[незручно](http://sum.in.ua/s/nezruchno)* (literary Ukrainian) means "inconveniently, uncomfortable" in general (and probably more like "awkwardly, embarrassingly" in this case).

*Получатись* (surzhyk) or *[виходити](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=11534&page=384)*, *[складатися](http://sum.in.ua/s/skladatysja)*, *[ставатися](http://sum.in.ua/s/stavatysja)* (literary Ukrainian) in this context means "to happen, to turn out":

- *получилось*, *вийшло*, *склалося*, *сталося* is past tense (something like Past Perfect).

So *як невдобно получилось* is something like "[oh] how uncomfortable it turned out" or simply "[oh] it's very embarassing", spoken in surzhyk.

AFAIK, this phrase comes from the anecdote about countryside newlyweds: after first intercourse during wedding night the fiance says "Didn't you say that you were a virgin before the wedding?" (implying that it appeared to be not truth) and the bride answers (feigning surprise) "Really?! Did I? Or, it's so embarrassing now" — i.e. it's easy to simulate repentance after you already got what you want in unfair manner.